# fabric and svn password

Tags: python, svn, fabric

Assuming that I cannot run something like this with Fabric:

`run("svn update --password 'password' .")`

how's the proper way to pass to Fabric the password for the remote interactive command line?

The problem is that the repo is checked out as svn+ssh and I don't have a http/https/svn option

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try SSHkey. It allows you to connect to the server without password.
In this case, you will have to setup a sshkey between your remote server and the repo.

At remote server: Generate key pair

```
 $ ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

Leave the passphase empty! 
This will generate 2 files

- ~/.ssh/id_dsa (private key)
- ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub (public key)

Then, append the content in id_dsa.pub to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys at repo server.

Your remote server will be able to update the source tree without any password required.

Comment: in the hope that someone is watching... - isn't leaving the passphrase empty a Bad Idea?

Comment: yes, an empty passphrase is not good in general - but it is no worse than putting the password into a script - and in this case, if the passphrase were not empty, you would need to script entering the SSH passphrase instead of the remote password so it would not accomplish much if anything.

Answer (score 3):

If yout just want to hide your password from log, you can use something like this:

```
from fabric.state import output

def xrun(command, hidden='', *args, **kwargs):
    old_state = output.running
    output.running = False
    print '[%s] run: %s' % (env.host_string, command)
    run(command + hidden, *args, **kwargs)
    output.running = command

xrun('svn update', '--password "your password"')
```

Answer (score 2):

We had a problem similar to this a while back and actually proposed a new feature for Fabric, but the developer we spoke to suggested this instead.

```
import getpass
password = getpass.getpass('Enter SVN Password: ')
run("svn update --password '%s'" % password)
```

This will prompt you for a password when the time comes for fabric to run this command.

I believe that will display your password in the fabric log, however, so a better option would be to get SVN to prompt you for the password and echo the password into it.

```
run('echo %s | svn update --password' % password)
```

I don't use SVN though, so I'm afraid I'm not sure if that is possible. I hope someone else can help there!

Comment: As I stated above svn update --password doesn't work at all, since that options is for http/https only.

Comment: What I am looking for is an automatic way of passing the password interactively.

Comment: Well, echoing your commands into SVN might still be worth a go. You should be able to echo the password into the interactive prompt, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

My standard answer for automating interactive command lines is "use Expect", but you're using Python, so I will slightly refine that to "use [Pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html)".

It might take a bit of thought to integrate Pexpect within Fabric, or perhaps you will just end up falling back to Pexpect alone for this particular case.  But it's definitely the way I would go.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to supply the user as well?  If not, you may have better luck exporting your repo and making a tar of it (locally) to upload+deploy on the server. If you run the svn commands locally, you'll be able to get prompted for your username and/or password.

Comment: I've tried supplying the --username switch as well, without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Fabric's env documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.0/usage/env.html). There states that you should make something like this:

```
from fabric.api import env

env.user = 'your_user'
env.password = 'your_password'
```

Hope it helps!